# Is ClickOnce a sandbox technology with features that are not opt-in?

Tags: .net, clickonce, sandbox

I was dinking around with click once on a locked down corporate machine (ssh! don't tell anyone) and some click once installation succeeded and ran, same as if the were portable applications, even though I was not an administrator and didn't have install rights.

Then I created an test .NET application and a ClickOnce installer. As the developer, I had to opt-in to sandboxing.  (If I was a malicious developer, I obviously would not opt-in to any sandboxing)  When I put on my end user hat and tried to install it, I got a yellow shield and something about how I should fear the internet, but no additional clues about what things this application might do, unlike say, an Android store app.

Does ClickOnce provide any sandboxing what so ever? Was it ever intended to be a sandboxing technology or it is just an alternative to .msi or setup.exe files?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/76e4d2xw%28v=VS.90%29.aspx

Comment: Yes, I use this resource too: google.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ClickOnce isn't a SandBox, but it does allow for SandBoxing.

A ClickOnce application is installed in the ClickOnce Application Cache, which is specific to the user (and is stored within obfuscated folders in the User's folder.)  However, if any network administrative settings block a user from being able to execute certain tasks, ClickOnce doesn't "magically" enable them.

Instead, ClickOnce provides a means for a developer to publish an application within a context that allows their users to have the ability to install a software package, even when they are not given direct permission to install system-wide software.  ClickOnce applications also have a data folder where information can be stored that should persist across updates or uninstall/reinstall cycles.  Even with that capability, a developer can create an application that does anything imaginable within Windows.  However, when the user goes to launch the application, if they do not have the associated permissions to execute such a task, the application will receive a permissions exception.

I hope that makes it a bit more clear.  If effect, ClickOnce applications are not special with elevated permissions.  ClickOnce applications are no different than what their counter-part would be if it was installed through MSI, with the exception of where the executables and working data are stored.  One mechanism is a little less restrictive of the installer than the other.  That's all.

Comment: This is not entirely true. ClickOnce, apps, by default, have more restrictions than a normal .NET app. For example, a ClickOnce apps don't allow ActiveX components to be minted unless the user agrees to elevated trust at the installation process. This was Microsoft's early attempts at limiting the permissions of a given app in order to make it safe enough to be installed on all computers. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/76e4d2xw(v=vs.85).aspx